# How can I find a const int* in an std::set<int*>?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, find, constants

First, I have a set

```
std::set<int*> my_set;
```

Then, I have a function for checking whether a specific int pointer `p` exists in `my_set`, that does nothing more than returning `true` if it the pointer exists in it, and `false` otherwise.

Since the function does not modify the referenced `int`, it is natural to take the pointer as a `const int*`, that is

```
bool exists_in_my_set(const int* p)
{
    return my_set.find(p) != my_set.end();
}
```

However, when I try to compile the code, I get the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'std::set<int*>::key_type {aka int*}' [-fpermissive]
```

In other words, the compiler tries to cast the `const int*` to an `int*` when I call `find`.

Anyway, my question is: *How can I find `p` in `my_set`, or at least find out whether `p` exists in `my_set` or not, using the existing definitions of `p` and `my_set`?*

Comment: `std::set<int*>::const_iterator` would allow you to modify the pointed-to `int`, so no `find` overload like you describe should exist. This seems like a valid reason to use `const_cast` to me.

Comment: I think you can use const_cast() to get rid of 'const' attribute temporarily.

Comment: There's no reason to overload `find`. You store `int*`, which means that the referenced objects can be modified!? Why then would you look for a reference to an object which cannot be modified?

Comment: @StoryTeller: I explained that in the question... "Since the function does not modify the referenced `int`, it is natural to take the pointer as a `const int*`"

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the textbook answer. You didn't stop to ponder if it makes sense in this case?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Do you mind to expand on that?

Comment: Maybe your set should store `const int*`s?

Comment: I already gave my reasoning. Since the objects referenced by the container can be altered, no true `const int` will ever be referenced by it. Using `const` to document the function won't change the object is silly in this case, since it can do it through `my_set` anyway.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: C++11 or C++03?

Comment: @StoryTeller: that reasoning isn't valid... a `const int*` isn't limited to referencing a `const int`, and that one part of the code happened to only need `const` access to an `int` doesn't mean it's unreasonable to want to know if the pointed-to `int` is known to the `set` (which has reason to want non-`const` access).  A simple `find() != end()` encapsulated in a function that clearly has access to the `set` doesn't even amount to granting the code with the `const` pointer non-`const` access.

Comment: @TonyD, and yet passing a `const int*` only to cast the constness away is deemed reasonable, why? Simply because it's "good practice" to pass a `const int*` when not changing the value? How is that valid reasoning?

Comment: @StroyTeller: the function has non-`const` access through `my_set`, but since it does not use that write access, it *does* make sense for it to accept an `int const*`. Otherwise, a function that itself only has an `int const*` would need a `const_cast` to call `exists_in_my_set`. This would be misleading, since there's no good reason to highlight that call as potentially const-unsafe provided that `exists_in_my_set` is correctly implemented. So as it happens, "good practice" does provide the correct approach in this case: it makes non-modifying functions callable from others without a cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the set like this

```
std::set<const int*> my_set;
```

...**if** you never need to modify an `int` by getting it's pointer from the set.  This might be the case if the lifetime* and values of the ints in the set are managed elsewhere and the set is just a method of checking if you're already aware of a particular int/object's existence.

(* although you can actually delete a `const int*`.)

Comment: This actually worked in my case! :) I guess that sometime when you find yourself in a tricky situation such as this one, you should ask yourself if the real problem is where you think it is.

Comment: I guess that by "delete a `const int*`" you mean remove it from the set?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `const_cast<>` to remove constness from the parameter before searching the `set<>`:

```
return my_set.find(const_cast<int*>(p)) != my_set.end();
```

There's no particular technical reason the library couldn't support allow what you expect, but on the other hand - forcing an explicit `const_cast` is documenting that an operation involving a `const` pointer is somehow getting non-`const` access through the `set`... arguably nice documentation that something a little unusual is up.

Comment: I upvoted this now because of the the second paragraph. I usually don't like answers which suggest practices without explaining them. This, along with the comment @SteveJessop wrote on the OP is very good.

Comment: Maybe this is the only good way if user1158692's method isn't applicable. On the other hand, what about reinterpreting `my_set` as an `std::set<const int*>` using `reinterpret_cast<std::set<const int*>&>(my_set)` to add constness, rather than removing constness? I don't know of the behavior of that method is well defined, but if it is, I guess that method would work as well.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: that would technically be undefined behaviour, and there's no reason to enter that territory when `const_cast<>` is available.  Practically, I'd expect it to work just fine in any real-world architecture/implementation.  Your cast implies additional instantiations of `find` and `end` for the different `set` template parameter, and probably the iterator type and comparison operator, but they'd all either be inlined or trivially small.

Comment: Well, I guessed it would be undefined, since there is no guarantee the member variables in all objects used by an `std::set<const int*>` lie exactly the same as they do in an std::set<int*>, even though it is likely that they do. Hence reinterpreting it as the other type was probably a bad idea.